# Android login screen that switches to tab layout?

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi I have an app written that after logging in correctly takes you to another page. Here is the code for the main page, when I had it directing to a plain page with an image it worked fine:

```
package com.example.loginscreen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private EditText  username=null;
   private EditText  password=null;
   private TextView attempts;
   private Button login;
   int counter = 3;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
      attempts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
      attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
      login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
   }

   public void login(View view){
      if(username.getText().toString().equals("mark") && 
      password.getText().toString().equals("mark")){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful!", 
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Loading.class)); 
       }    
   else{
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      attempts.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);   
      counter--;
      attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
      if(counter==0){
         login.setEnabled(false);
      }

       }

 }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return true;
    }

 }
```

which switches to a tab layout with the following activities:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomePage extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("Overview");
        setContentView(textview);
    }
}



package com.example.loginscreen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomePage2 extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("Card Summary");
        setContentView(textview);
    }
}



package com.example.loginscreen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomePage3 extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("Details");
        setContentView(textview);
    }
}
```

Which all link through this:

```
package com.example.loginscreen;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class LinkTabs extends TabActivity {

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.link_main);

        Resources ressources = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 

        // First tab
        Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, HomePage.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecHomePage = tabHost
          .newTabSpec("HomePage")
          .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.overview))
          .setContent(intentAndroid);

        // Second tab
        Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, HomePage2.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecHomePage2 = tabHost
          .newTabSpec("HomePage2")
          .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.overview))
          .setContent(intentApple);

            // Third tab
        Intent intentWindows = new Intent().setClass(this, HomePage3.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecHomePage3 = tabHost
          .newTabSpec("HomePage3")
          .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.overview))
          .setContent(intentWindows);


        // add all tabs 
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecHomePage);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecHomePage2);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecHomePage3);


        //set Windows tab as default (zero based)
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }

}
```

But whenever I run the app it brings up the first activity which does everything fine but then if you log in correctly the app just stops. There are no errors, and here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.loginscreen"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="10"
  android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

  <activity
     android:name="com.example.loginscreen.MainActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
  </activity>
<activity android:name=".HomePage" />
<activity android:name=".HomePage2" />
<activity android:name=".HomePage3" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the xml for the main page:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:ems="10"
    tools:ignore="TextFields" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText1"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:text="@string/password"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:text="TextView"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:text="@string/username"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/tranzlogo1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="@string/attempts"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:onClick="login"
    android:text="@string/Login" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the link page for tab layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Logcat:

```
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3603)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4103)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17117)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3598)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    ... 11 more
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.loginscreen/com.example.loginscreen.LinkTabs}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1541)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    at com.example.loginscreen.MainActivity.login(MainActivity.java:40)
06-19 16:25:04.175: E/AndroidRuntime(16791):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: `the app just stops` which means what? What happens? Do you see the crash dialog? If so: what can you see in the Logcat?

Comment: when I run it ut says 'Unfortunately LoginScreen has stopped', I'll post the logcat

Comment: Can you add the XML for your  login page? What happens if you make the login page your default XML to start the app with? Does this crash too?

Comment: I do not see any logcat...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message is:

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.loginscreen/com.example.loginscreen.LinkTabs}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

The answer to that question is obvious: There is no `<activity name=".LinkTabs"/>` tag in your manifest. Just add it and it should work.